# Does Stack Overflow encourage asking whenever there is a good question, or only when it is absolutely needed?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Stack Overflow is a Q&A platform that is based on the premise of people being willing to ask and answer. As a student and learner, I often have much to ask and not much to answer.

Does Stack Overflow encourage the act of asking whenever there is a good question, because this is considered healthy for the platform, or does it consider asking to be demanding of resources and to be limited when possible?

Comment: If people were hesitant to ask questions then there wouldn't be as many to answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there is a guiding principle, it is this: *Don't waste people's time.*

Also this: *Asking good questions is hard.*

That said, if you are willing to make your question clear, answerable, and of interest to at least one other programmer, we'll give it our best shot.

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) contain plenty of guidance on how to ask good questions.

Comment: ....and as long as it's not a duplicate!

Comment: The other answer suggesting the opposite was deleted. Was this a moderation act? Should I then consider this as the right answer, definitedly?

Comment: Andrew deleted his own answer.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Anyway, it is obvious that this is the community opinion. Thanks.

Comment: It would be also great if all this was also applicable to a call center.